# OAuth2.0 Authorization Code Grant with PKCE

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a rest api built in spring boot. A front end application in react. I have users who should be able to log in and access their information e.g. orders. My Auth server (OAuth2.1) issues JWT tokens using Authorization Code Grant PKCE. Flow works fine on the first iteration however when user logs out and I want to login using different user, auth server doesn't show up the login page and straight away issues new JWT token for the old user (which logged out earlier). Looks like auth server stores the session of the user somewhere. Both client (React JS) and auth server belongs to me.

Just to be clear, here is the flow.

Click Login > verifier & challenge generated > Auth server gives Login Form > 'Tom' enters credentials > Token issued > Tom logs out

Click Login > new verifier & challenge generated > Token issued without showing up login page

Problem with this is, on the 2nd iteration, I can not login as a different user. On the logout I am invalidating the session and deleting the cookies as well .. here is the code snippet --> (.logout() .invalidateHttpSession(true) .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")) .permitAll() .and()

Also I am clearing session and localStorage at react front end

React front end generates verifier and code challenge then call Spring Auth server endpoints, ../oauth2/authorize and /oauth2/token respectively.

I've implemented default /logout

Comment: Which part of your application is an OAuth2 client - React or Spring (who exchanges code for tokens)? Do you call the OAuth2 server's logout endpoint (end_session_endpoint from the discovery document)?

Comment: React front end generates verifier and code challenge then call Spring Auth server endpoints, ../oauth2/authorize and /oauth2/token respectively.

Yes I've implemented default /logout